# How to change text colour of specific labels of axis in Chart JS?

Tags: jquery, charts, chart.js

How to change text colour of specific labels of axis in Chart JS?
[image]

Comment: I don't believe it's possible in ChartJS to change individual label styling. You can change it, but it affects all labels on an axis/dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tick color as stated [in the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration):

```
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "white",
                    fontSize: 18,
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "white",
                    fontSize: 14,
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html to see what formats you can define colors in.

**EDIT:** I now see that you wanted to set colors for *specific* labels. As far as I can find, there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible (at least for now, version 2.9, maybe in upcoming releases).

`ticks.fontColor` is neither scriptable nor indexable.

One thing you could do is coloring the gridlines above the ticks.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
      color: ['#F00', '#0F0', '#F00', '#F00']
    }]
  }
}
```

You can hard-code the colors or use a function to give every grid line a color.

Answer (score -1):

There are 4 special global settings that can change all of the fonts on the chart. These options are in Chart.defaults.global. The global font settings only apply when more specific options are not included in the config.

For example, in this chart the text will all be red except for the labels in the legend.

```js
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'red';
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        legend: {
            labels: {
                // This more specific font property overrides the global property
                fontColor: 'black'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Read the question again. The OP wants to change ***specific*** labels, not *all* of the labels.

Comment: Also, [regurgitating the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html) isn't an answer.